# How to check and find potential functions given a force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work

I was given a force, let's say $F = 15xy$ N to the right which moves a system from $A(0,0)$ to $B(3,4)$ and was to find the work done by the force, in Joules.

My approach was by using $\vec{F} = -\vec{\nabla}U$ to find the potential energy in $A(0,0)$ and the potential energy in $B(3,4)$, then using the relationship that $W = -\Delta U$ to find the work done.

Although, I have problems on how to find $U$ based on the equation $\vec{F} = -\vec{\nabla}U$. Based on the problem, I made $\vec{F} = 15 xy \hat{i}$ but I have no luck finding the $U$.

The choices to the problem (in Joules): $540, 405, 1080, 1280, 2700$. I tried another way but the answer was not in the multiple-choice.

Comment: There is no basis vector attached to force? Or is $ F = xy \vec{i}$...?

Comment: Do you know the direction of $\vec{F}$? I think you should try the integral formula for work.

Comment: @Buraian The problem only says the force is directed to the right, so I assumed it was in the $\hat{i}$ direction. There was no path given, so I assumed that it's conservative, but I just found out that there's no way for that force to be conservative?

Comment: @JulianDeV Yeah, I assumed "right"  to be in the direction of $\hat{i}$ but I've got no luck continuing it because the problem doesn't tell me the path the particle took. The previous problems given to me has it but this one doesn't.

Comment: I wrote an answer, does it help?

Comment: Well it can't be purely to the right, because the particle also goes upwards. You could try a straight line from (0,0) to (3,4), projecting the force onto it through the scalar product and then taking the integral over some affine parameter which parametrises the straight line.

Comment: @JulianDeV I guess the problem is the problem itself. My last attempt integrating it with the assumption it goes on a straight line, the answer was not in the multiple choice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose our force has expression as shown below:

$$ F = F_x \vec{i} + F_y \vec{j} + F_z \vec{k}$$

If a potential function $U$ exists then,

$$ F = -\nabla U   = -[\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} \vec{i} + \frac{\partial U}{\partial y} \vec{j}+ \frac{\partial U}{\partial z} \vec{k}]$$

Now, you can compare any one of the coefficients, say we do $x$,

$$- \frac{ \partial U}{\partial x}  = F_x$$

We can run a definite integral on both sides to get the potential:

$$ U =  - \int F_x dx + h(y,z)$$

We need to include the extraneous $ h(y,z)$ term as all function of that form is differentiated to zero when derivated with $x$. Keeping it in their lets us fit the potential with other force components. So, we must find $h(y,z)$ such that the following system is satisfied:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \frac{ \partial U}{\partial y} \\ \frac{ \partial U}{\partial z} \end{bmatrix} = - \begin{bmatrix} F_y \\ F_z \end{bmatrix}$$

Also, to check that a potential function exists, just need to check that force field is irrational  that is:

$$ \nabla \times F = 0$$

For this case:

$$ ( \frac{ \partial}{\partial x} \vec{i} + \frac{ \partial}{\partial y} \vec{j} + \frac{ \partial}{\partial z} \vec{k}) \times (xy \vec{i}) $$

Doesn't seem this one is conservative   This problem seems to be unsolvable unless you specify a path. Without a lack of context, I'd assume they mean a straight-line path.

**On further thought:** The force can be made to be conservative if assume that 'right' means the $ \vec{k}$ direction i.e:

$$ F= xy \vec{k}$$

---

[Refer here for more information](https://mathinsight.org/conservative_vector_field_find_potential)

Comment: I see. I'll stick with the straight-line path one, then, even though the answer is not in the multiple-choice. Thanks!